# SQL query get only parent directory

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT *
FROM directory
WHERE status_id = 10 AND workspace_id = 1
```

[image]

Above is my query and database table.

**dir_name** = directory name

**dir_path** = directory path

For example, **BbB** is a nested directory under **AaA**.

How can I write a query for this when I call the above data, instead of all 5 rows display, only show 1 row, the parent directory. In this case, only **id = 13** data will show because  it was the parent directory for all of the data.

Comment: please use plain text or table markdown to display tables, and also include some DDL for sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a idea using `length` and `replace` to indicate the layer of a folder/file, so not just finding the parent folder/file you can find what ever layer you want assuming your `dir_path` will always formmat in `aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd`

```
select tb.*,len(dir_path) - len(replace(dir_path,'\','')) as layer 
from [tablename] tb
where len(dir_path) - len(replace(dir_path,'\','')) = 1
```

and here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=20cd5c11d6c67617fe3fc3b1b0d2dbe9)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the idea mate.

Answer (score 2):

I assume for the condition, the directory structure will be parent & corresponding children. In that case, you can go for simple query.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM directory
WHERE status_id = 10 AND workspace_id = 1
ORDER BY LEN(dir_path) ASC -- shortest directory path
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM directory
WHERE status_id = 10 AND workspace_id = 1 AND
      dir_path NOT LIKE '_%\%';
```

That is, there is no slash in the middle of the string.